# Why does TouchableOpacity automatically trigger onPress in ReactNative Expo Snack?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a small ReactNative app in [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/sR1dUcC6M) that includes a single components with a TouchableOpacity.

```
export default function AssetExample() {
  function clicked() {
    alert('clicked')
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={clicked()}>  
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Click the icon
        </Text>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/snack-icon.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>  
    </View>
  );
}
```

Every time the app is started the alert is shown, meaning `TouchableOpacity` triggers `onPress`. Why? And how can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the reference of your function to TouchableOpacity like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={clicked}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

or pass it with arrow function

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> clicked()}>  
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

so it will be called inside TouchableOpacity component whenever required (button click), otherwise it will be called only one time during render phase.

See these docs for handling events in React https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html